# How can I know which values were changed in Django's Model.save() method?

Tags: python, django

I have overwritten the Django's Model.save() method in order to perform manipulations on an external database when an object is added or updated.

Basically, here's my method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):    
    if self.pk is None:
        # Insert query on the external database.
    else:
        # Update query on the external database.

    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

My question is now, I know I can access the data submitted just by doing self.name for example, but how can I access the old data? I mean, the existing data, in the case of an update of course.

Because here's my problem, the external database doesn't support lots of queries and I want to do the query only if the field in question was updated.

Here is what I would like to do:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):    
    if self.pk is None:
        # Insert query on the external database.
    else:
        if self.name is not self.THE_CURRENT_NAME
            # Update query on the external database.

    super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to fetch it from the DB before the saving:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):    
    if self.pk is None:
        # Insert query on the external database.
    else:
        old = Lab.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
        if self.name is not old.name:
            ...             

    super(Lab, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: He said he want to avoid queries and your solution adds one.

Comment: He said the _external_ DB doesn't support many queries, not the local one. Eitherway, there's no other approach (AFAIK) via the `save` method

Comment: Of course there is. Override `__init__` method to store `_original_name` and compare to it later in `save`.

Comment: "via the `save` method", i.e. what the OP asked for

Comment: furthermore, overwriting the `__init__` is dangerous. If the attribute get's saved more then once in it's lifetime, `_original_name` will reference the wrong value (the value it had when created, not the most recent value)

Comment: It is better to keep the value up-to-date then making additional query on each save. We're solving the wrong problem here. This is already covered in django in forms – which servers manipulating data.

Comment: The solution from Timmy O'Mahony solves my problem fine. Thanks guys!

Comment: @KrzysiekSzularz agreed ;) There are definitely better ways to approach the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `ModelForm` for the job, override `save` method on it and decide whether to cascade to model's `save` (call `super` with `commit=True`) or not.

You probably have all the information at this point. Now you need a way to use it.

Forms in django have tools for what you need. Check out `changed_data` attribute and `has_changed()` method of  the form.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def save(commit=True):
        if self.has_changed():
            super(MyModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)
```

Answer (score 0):

so you want to get your data from the database, and you don't want to make many queries. If your data is not too much, you can just read all the data from your database to the memory, and then compare your about-to-save value with the data in memory, if they are not the same, just assign that value to the memory data as well as updating in the database.